# Handling multiple call to a script

Tags: javascript, embed

I'm working in an embed script while loads `HTML` form with `JS` validation while loaded in web pages. For now only one script loads on a page. If we add more embed script on a single page, the last added or loaded one will work & its related form & validation will execute. What I'm trying is to run multiple embed scripts in a single page.

Here is the **current embed script pattern** which is placed in HTML page:

```
<script src="http://link-to-my-embed-code-executer/embed_form.js"></script>
<div id="12345wertyui67890" class="form_wrap"><!-- HTML form with validation loads here --></div>
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        EmbedManager.embed({
            key:"12345wertyui67890",
            is_embed_form:"1",
            external_style:"1"
        })
    }
</script>
```

Here is the **current script in embed_form.js**

```
var EmbedManager = {
    key: '',
    is_embed_form: !0,
    external_style: 0,
    resizeCallback: function() {},
    init: function(embedParams) {
        EmbedManager.key = embedParams.key;
        EmbedManager.is_embed_form = embedParams.is_embed_form;
        EmbedManager.external_style = embedParams.external_style;
        EmbedManager.serverUrl = ''; // Here is the URL which provide HTML Form as response
    },
    embed: function(embedParams) {

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', EmbedManager.serverUrl);        
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
        xhr.onload = function() {
            if (xhr.status !== 200) {
                document.getElementById(EmbedManager.key).innerHTML = "Unable to load form"
            }
            var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

            // Attempt to get the element using document.getElementById
            var elementDOC = document.getElementById(EmbedManager.key);
            // If it isn't "undefined" and it isn't "null", then it exists.
            if ((typeof(elementDOC) != 'undefined') && (elementDOC != null) && (EmbedManager.is_embed_form)) {
                // Only for Form, not used in LP
                document.getElementById(EmbedManager.key).innerHTML = response.form_html;
            }
        }

        // More code here to load Form in place of embed script & do validations

    }
}
```

I'm trying to manage the updates in `JS` file because embed scripts are already provided to clients & I'm not interested in making bigger updates in those embed scripts. If it could be handled inside the `JS` file, it will be better.

What I'm trying to do is add a new function `remapEmbed` which will be a copy of codes in current `embed` function & also after that will replace codes in `embed` function to such a manner to collect multiple requests from embed scripts & make an array, later I will call `remapEmbed` function to do the rest. I know little changes will be needed there also, I will look into it later.

Here is the **expected script in embed_form.js**

```
var EmbedManager = {
    key: '',
    is_embed_form: !0,
    external_style: 0,
    resizeCallback: function() {},
    init: function(embedParams) {
        EmbedManager.key = embedParams.key;
        EmbedManager.is_embed_form = embedParams.is_embed_form;
        EmbedManager.external_style = embedParams.external_style;
    },
    remapEmbed: function(embedParams) {
        // Code which was in `embed` function
        // More code here to load Form in place of embed script & do validations
    },
    embed: function(embedParams) {
        // Code to collect request & make a array
        // Expecting to add codes here

        // Later will call `remapEmbed` function & do rest.
        EmbedManager.remapEmbed(embedParamsOne);
    }
}
```

But the issue is that I'm getting only the call from the last embed script which is added on the page. It might be because of the last call overwriting the previous ones. How can I handle multiple requests?

Here I'm adding the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/SintoDematech/pen/eYJrmpr), so you can check the code.

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, you cannot place multiple onload events on a single
> page. You can nest multiple functions within the one onload call. [Ref](http://www.brefere.com/fbapps/bcom.nsf/cvbdate/D514491209EE5C848725801A0074AE6E?opendocument#:%7E:text=Unfortunately%2C%20you%20cannot%20place%20multiple,have%20an%20existing%20onload%20event%3F)

It working fine with Your script. Because you are calling embed scripts in Onload. Make sure all scripts inside last `window.onload` function.

Change html to

```
<!-- The embed code that will not replace with the response -->
<div id="12345AAA67890" class="form_wrap">HTML form with validation loads here: First Embed Code</div>

<!-- This embed code will be replaced with HTML content -->
<div id="12345BBB67890" class="form_wrap">HTML form with validation loads here: Second Embed Code</div>
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        EmbedManager.embed({
            key:"12345BBB67890",
            is_embed_form:"1",
            external_style:"1"
        })
      EmbedManager.embed({
            key:"12345AAA67890",
            is_embed_form:"1",
            external_style:"1"
        })
    }
</script>
```

Hope this is the solution you are looking.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem is that as I explained in the question, the script that you are asking to combine is an embed code. Single embed scripts are using in pages we can't give a combined script to external users.

Comment: What I'm trying is to combine the embed scripts in my embed js file. But I'm not getting multiple calls from embed script.

Comment: Fine @Sinto. I gone through the fiddle and gave reply. Can you gone through

http://www.brefere.com/fbapps/bcom.nsf/cvbdate/D514491209EE5C848725801A0074AE6E?opendocument#:%7E:text=Unfortunately%2C%20you%20cannot%20place%20multiple,have%20an%20existing%20onload%20event%3F

Comment: Yes, I do not think that it solves my issues but will check it.